How to configure PyArmor (latest version) to make obfuscated scripts runnable on multiple devices
I am using the latest version of PyArmor to obfuscate my Python scripts. By default, PyArmor tends to bind the obfuscated code to a specific device or environment for security reasons. However, I need to make the obfuscated scripts portable so they can run on multiple devices without restrictions.
Is there a command line to configure PyArmor for generating obfuscated scripts that are not bound to a specific device?
